# Unusual import of a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a file `exceptions.py` present in `kubernetes.client` folder where `ApiException` class is defined. So I can write the following line in my own file say `myfile.py` and use the `ApiException` for raising exception.

**some_folder.myfile.py code snippet:**

```
from kubernetes.client.exceptions import ApiException
.....
.....
    try:
        .....
    except ApiException as e:
        .....
```

That is fine.

Also in `rest.py` present in `kubernetes.client` folder is importing the same class `ApiException` and raising some exception.

**kubernetes.client.rest.py code snippet:**

```
from kubernetes.client.exceptions import ApiException
.....
.....
     if not 200 <= r.status <= 299:
         raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
```

That is also fine. But I am pretty much confused to see the below things as `ApiException` is imported from `kubernetes.client.rest` in `some_file.py` file (see below), **not** from `kubernetes.client.exceptions` where actual class definition for `ApiException` is present.

**some_folder.some_file.py code snippet:**

```
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
.....
.....
    try:
       .....
    except ApiException as e:
       .....
```

The above code is working but I am really surprised. Can somebody explain me what is happening here. Sorry I am new to Python.

**Note:**

1. ApiException class is not defined in `kubernetes.client.rest`, it is only defined in `kubernetes.client.exceptions`
2. I have searched many articles at online but did not get much information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `ApiException` is also defined in `kubernetes.client.rest`, because it's been imported there. `kubernetes.client.rest` is using it, so it exists there. Any name that exists at the top level of a module is an attribute of that module and can be imported from elsewhere. It doesn't matter how that name got to be defined there.

Arguably the class should be imported from its *canonical* location where it has been defined, but it doesn't have to be. `some_folder.some_file.py` might not know where the exception has been originally defined, if it only interacts with `kubernetes.client.rest` and just needs to catch exceptions raised there.

---

You will often see this technique used in `__init__.py` files to simply re-export some classes defined in submodules under a simpler name, e.g.:

```
# foo/__init__.py
from .submodule import Foo
from .othermodule import Bar
```

This allows users of `foo` to `from foo import Foo`, instead of having to do `from foo.submodule import Foo`, but it still keeps the implementation of `foo` clean and separated into multiple files.